# Mapping Between US SIC Code to UK SIC 2007

Tags: data-request, data.gov

I've been tasked with mapping USA SIC code such as 59990903 - Retail sale of hearing aids, to the UK 2007 equivalent (47741).

However, the only docs I can find online are for USA SIC to NAISC codes translations, or US to the UK but for older editions in the 80s/90s where it seems to be only 4 digits rather than 8.

If there is a resource somewhere for this then you would be a lifesaver!